# PHP error when using a variable name with a minus sign

Tags: php, html

Here is my code:

```
if($number == 1){
   $output-number = "output";
}
```

But everytime I get an error message: `syntax error, unexpected '='`, and I don't know why. I searched now a long time, but I didn't find a helpful answer.

Comment: you can't use `-` in variable name, allowed characters a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and _(underscore)

Comment: This question doesn't deserve the downvotes. Though it's trivial to PHP/Java/C programmers, it may be confusing to people coming from other languages, which do allow minus signs in identifiers. E.g. the Scheme language. Or CSS.

Answer (score 2):

PHP does *not* allow minus sign as part of a variable name. Use an underscore, i.e. change `$output-number` to `$output_number`. Or use camel-case style: `$outputNumber`.

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
$output_number = "output";
```

Comment: it would be more helpful with description